# Image Slider in JS not working

Tags: javascript, html, image

I used the following code for a js slider. But it only shows the first image:

In the head tag:

```
<script>
var slideimages = new Array()
slideimages[0] = new Image() 
slideimages[0].src = 'mini.jpg';
slideimages[1] = new Image() 
slideimages[1].src = 'windows8.1.png';
slideimages[2] = new Image() 
slideimages[2].src = 'jw.jpg';
slideimages[3] = new Image() 
slideimages[3].src = 'aau.jpg';
slideimages[4] = new Image() 
slideimages[4].src = 'f7.jpg';
</script>
```

In the Body Tag:-

```
<script>
var step = 0
var whichimage = 0

function slideit() {
    if (!document.images) return
    document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
    whichimage = step;
    setTimeout('slideit()', 2500);
    if (step < 4) {
        step++;
    } else {
        step = 0;
    }
}

function slidelink() {
    if (whichimage == 0) {
        window.open('movies.php#mini');
    }
    if (whichimage == 1) {
        window.open('software.php#win8.1');
    }
    if (whichimage == 2) {
        window.open('movies.php#jw');
    }
    if (whichimage == 3) {
        window.open('movies.php#aau');
    }
    if (whichimage == 4) {
        window.open('movies.php#f7');
    }
    slideit(); 
</script>  
<a href='javascript:slidelink()'><img src='mini.jpg' id='slide' width='640px' height='640px' /></a>
```

Comment: Try `setTimeout(slideit, 2500);`. Any errors?

Comment: Is it because you haven't closed your `slidelink` function? It's missing a `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you never closed your `slidelink` function which will throw an error and make your code not work.
Add a `}` at the end of the function and it should work:

```
function slidelink() {
    if (whichimage == 0) {
        window.open('movies.php#mini');
    }
    if (whichimage == 1) {
        window.open('software.php#win8.1');
    }
    if (whichimage == 2) {
        window.open('movies.php#jw');
    }
    if (whichimage == 3) {
        window.open('movies.php#aau');
    }
    if (whichimage == 4) {
        window.open('movies.php#f7');
    }
    slideit();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/furLqp0k/)

Just check your console. That way you can avoid these kind of mistakes / questions.